# Tests pass in GHCI but fail in cabal test

Tags: haskell, ghc, cabal

**UPDATE** After I added the `haskeline` dependency, the tests passed.

It appears that `cabal test` cannot find my test cases even though `cabal build` runs fine. Below is the output of `cabal test` (which fails), and then the output of running the test executable's `main` in GHCI (which passes).

```
cabal test
Running 1 test suites...
Test suite test-one: RUNNING...
test-one: <stdin>: hGetLine: end of file
Test suite test-one: FAIL
Test suite logged to: dist/test/one-0.1.0.0-test-one.log
0 of 1 test suites (0 of 1 test cases) passed.

main
Cases: 3  Tried: 3  Errors: 0  Failures: 0
Counts {cases = 3, tried = 3, errors = 0, failures = 0}
```

Here's the test code that produces these outputs:

```
module Tests (
    main
) where

import Data.Char
import Control.Monad
import System.IO
import System.Directory
import Test.HUnit
import Test.QuickCheck
import Main (four)


test1 = TestCase $ assertEqual "test upCase" "FOO" (map toUpper "foo")
test2 = TestCase $ assertEqual "testing that the result is 4" 4 4 
test3 = TestCase $ assertEqual "testing that 4 is 4" four 4

tests = TestList [TestLabel "test1" test1, TestLabel "test2" test2, TestLabel "test3" test3]

main = runTestTT $ tests
```

What should I change to please cabal?

My `.cabal` file contains:

```
executable one
  main-is:             Main.hs
  other-modules:       Utils
  build-depends:       base ==4.6.*, mongoDB ==1.4.*, mtl ==2.1.*, directory ==1.2.*, text ==0.11.*, HUnit ==1.2.*, QuickCheck ==2.6.*
  hs-source-dirs:      src, tests

Test-Suite test-one
    type:              exitcode-stdio-1.0
    main-is:           Tests.hs
    hs-source-dirs:    src, tests
    build-depends:     base ==4.6.*, mongoDB ==1.4.*, mtl ==2.1.*, directory ==1.2.*, text ==0.11.*, HUnit ==1.2.*, QuickCheck ==2.6.*
```

Comment: Have you specified a `Test-Suite` in your .cabal file?

Comment: Please show us the .cabal file.

Answer (score 2):

You should rename the module `Tests` to `Main`, otherwise the test executable won't be built. Quoting the [Haskell Report](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/modules.html):

> A Haskell *program* is a collection of modules, one of which, by
>   convention, must be called `Main` and must export the value `main`.

Otherwise I don't see anything obviously wrong. Here's a working example based on your code: https://gist.github.com/23Skidoo/8019225

Perhaps you're using an old version of `cabal`? Consider upgrading to 1.18.